# Reading, writing and speaking improvement app

Tags: educational, reading

I am looking for a mobile application (Android or iOS) to improve reading, writing and speaking skills of kids aged 12-15 years.

I care about English and Arabic languages.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reviews, [DuoLingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) is a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [Fluent Forever](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/fluent-forever-app-think-in-any-new-language#/) app, though this is still in development so you'll have to keep an eye on it.

The creator of the program/method [does recommend using Anki flashcards](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/fluent-forever-app-think-in-any-new-language#/) meanwhile as part of the method of learning.